# Actions are shared within different browser and tabs React Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I followed one great tutorial and when I have finished I noticed that
if in the same time from 2 different browsers FF, Chrome, Opera I am working with this project all the actions are shared to another, looks like they store same sessions in one, what could provoke this issue?

The repo from the tutorial https://github.com/codereviewvideos/react-login-registration.git

If pull this repo and start it I have the same effect.
Thank you.

Comment: It probably talks to a PHP backend, otherwise there's no session sharing between different browsers possible, none that I know of at least.

Comment: Yes but there is none of back-end working during the tests

Comment: Nothing in the tests in this repo suggest that they sync anything between browsers or tabs. Can you describe your question better? What does "actions are shared to another" mean?

Comment: When I run application and open 2 browsers FF and chrome on the application port like localhost:3000 and press a button in FF for example the same action result will appear in the chrome.

Comment: Are you saying that **user input** you made in the app in one browser appears in *the other* browser? What do you mean by "same action result"?

Comment: yes you are right user input in one browser appears in all others

Comment: That‘s some server-side hot reloading. Don‘t obsess over it, rarely needed for most apps. More of a gimmick. The browser is polling the backend for updates with setInterval probably.

Comment: Check your project's modules list (i.e. dependencies in package.json) and make sure that you are not running it via  'browser-sync'.

Comment: How can I disable serving files through browser-sync? And run it in production mode? because on npm run build it creates and servers from /dist directory but anyway with broser-sync....